# Open google calendar settings web page from C# app

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, credentials

I am developing an app that syncs with Google Calendar api v3.

Syncing events and retrieving calendars is working fine, but being a bit tight on time and resources, and as I'd rather not re-invent the wheel, the app should use Google's "Settings" web-page to manage advanced stuff (create new calendars, manage sharing, time-zones etc...).

Open an URL using C# is quite straight forward with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/calendar");
```

But the tricky parts are:

1. How to use the application's stored credentials for the web session?
2. How to open directly the account's settings page?
3. Hot to open directly a calendar's settings page, given its Id?

Comment: To answer question 2: this URL should work to go directly to the settings: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#settings-general_11

Comment: @Matt Sorry doesn't work, that opens the main calendar view...

Comment: What's the url you get when going to the settings page?

Comment: something similar but with a different number. Now I invite you to test yourself - copy the url when you are in your settings, logout and paste the url - you'll be redirected to login page and, after login, you'll get to the main calendar screen, not the settings...